# Line Break means something in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, parsing

I´m merging two branches of a software, and in the process of merging, some code stayed like that:

```
if (b_flag)
 DoSomething();
 //MERGE
else
 //ENDMERGE
  DoOtherThing();
```

See the disconnection of the if/ else block ? This works like supposted to do ? Compilers take line breaks in consideration ?

Comment: What "disconnection"?  The only thing wrong with this code is the missing semicolons after the function calls; whitespace is not significant here.

Comment: I never really appreciated this particular point of syntax, I find it much better to use curly braces every time, even for single statements... when you begin to wonder if a statement belongs or not to a block, you're apt to be going crazy :/

Comment: If you know C, you're not going to begin to wonder. This is basic idiomatic C you should learn in the first few days of learning the language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it will work like it's supposed to. When you have an `if` or `else` with no curly braces (`{}`), the next statement is treated as being the body of the if. Inserting line breaks or comments doesn't change the fact that DoSomething(); or DoOtherThing(); are these statements.

Comment: Thanks god for your education. A straight answer for my question.

Answer (score 6):

Even though comments are effectively handled like whitespace, so it will work like it's "supposed to do".  However, you probably should add curly braces to this code before something goes horribly wrong.

Eventually, with the extra comments, a person will miss the else statement, or worse yet a extra statement will get added to the "if block" and the else statement will suddenly become an else statement for some higher nesting if statement which lacks an else.

A good style is to enforce the mandatory inclusion of curly braces in all but the most simple of cases.

Answer (score 2):

A newline is not any different than a space or a tab. Comments are not considered statements, by the way -- they are simply ignored by the compiler.

Edit: The only time a newline matters is inside a C preprocessor directive, such as `#define`.

Comment: but not in the middle of a define or a string literal

Comment: Consider a comment to be replaced by a single space character.

Answer (score 1):

This works exactly as if braces were used.